# How to dynamically move A element into a horizontal line with jquery

Tags: jquery, soundcloud, progress

I've created a custom Soundcloud Player with the widget api and a graphic progress bar made in this way:

```
<a id="slider-handle" href="#" style="left: 0"></a>
```

I dynamically move the left attribute following the current position of the track (I did a conversion from milliseconds to a percentage value). And this works fine. Now I would let the people to seek through the song moving this anchor element back and forth (like a range input). Is it possible to do this with jquery?

Here is the full code, which is more clear if you try it playing a song in the right-bottom corner: http://jsfiddle.net/7s2joet2/27/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll have a go at this:

First, you need to set `draggable="false"` on the `#slider-handle` because browsers that support HTML5 drag & drop will show the 'forbidden' cursor when you drag it ([image]).

We need the following properties to accurately position the drag handle:

- `Event.clientX`: the current x coordinate of the cursor
- `Element.clientWidth`: the rendered width of the element in pixels
- `Element.offsetLeft`: the rendered offset of the element in pixels from the left of the page

We need flags to keep track of state (has the user clicked? has the user left the widget?):

- `isToggled`: `true` when a user clicks the progress bar or handle
- `isMdown`: `true` when a user clicks the handle

Adding the following code to yours, and changing some of the existing code:

```
var isMdown     = false,    // gets set to true when user clicks the handle
    isToggled = false,  // gets set to true when user clicks the bar or handle
    progress    = $('#progress'),
    percentage= null,   // keeps track of the last % 
    handleW     = 8,            // width of the handle, req. for positioning
    handle      = document.getElementById('slider-handle'),
    range       = document.getElementById('slider-range');

// main position adjustment function
var setPos = function(e) {
  var posxBuffer = e.clientX - progress.offset().left,
      w = this.clientWidth;
  widget.getDuration(function(duration){
    widget.seekTo(percentage*duration/100);
    handle.style.left = percentage + '%';
    range.style.width = percentage + '%';
  });
  isToggled = false;
  isMdown   = false;
};

// we just need to update the % value here and set some flags
progress.on('mousedown', function(e) {
  isToggled = true;
  var posxBuffer = e.clientX - progress.offset().left,
      w = this.clientWidth;
  percentage = ((posxBuffer-handleW)*100)/w;
  if (e.target === handle)
    isMdown = true;
});

progress.on('mouseover', function(e) {
  // if the user has previously triggered a mousedown event, he is now dragging
  // => adjust handle position, but not time progress
  if (isMdown) {
    var posxBuffer = e.clientX- progress.offset().left,
        w = this.clientWidth;
    percentage = ((posxBuffer-handleW)*100)/w;
    handle.style.left = percentage + '%';
    range.style.width = percentage + '%';
  }
});

// when a user has clicked the progress bar and releases the button,
// set the position
progress.on('mouseup', setPos);

// when a user is still dragging but leaves the progress bar, 
// release and set to last position
progress.on('mouseleave', function(e) {
  if (isMdown)
    setPos(e);
});

widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY_PROGRESS, function(){
  widget.getPosition(function(position){
    widget.getDuration(function(duration){
       $('#seekms').text(duration);  
       // Just as a bonus, the code for transforming ms into a MM:SS format =)
       var mins = (position/1000/60 < 10 ? '0' : '') + Math.floor(position/1000/60),
           secs = (position/1000%60 < 10 ? '0' : '') + Math.floor((position/1000) %60);
       $('#bufferms').text(mins + ':' + secs);
       // only updated if the user already moused down on either handler or bar
       if (isToggled || isMdown)
          return;
       var percentage = position*100/duration;
       $("#slider-range").css("width", percentage + '%');
       $("#slider-handle").css("left", percentage + '%');
                 $('#inputseek').val(percentage);
    });
  });
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/7s2joet2/31/ (note: I made the handle + bar bigger so it'd be easier to drag)

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is great! It works well on jsfiddle but I got some problems when implemented it on my real page: [link](http://www.wearegoingsolo.com/top-50-songs-of-2015) (it's still under construction). When i try to drag the bar it goes always in the middle, it should be a problem of width but I don't understand where the problem is. It would be great if you could still help me!

Comment: I found out that the calc of `posxBuffer` was wrong, cause I had a margin-left on the content. So I had to remove 193px (even though the margin was only 139px, don't know where the remains 54px are) in the calc of `posxBuffer`. But I still think I did a little mess with the general css of the player, cause of course if I restrict the window width, everything goes wrong.

Comment: The problem is that the player is in a `.div { width:70%; left: 15%; right:15%; }`. If the player starts from `left: 0px;` it works well

Comment: @Eldar88 Yes you were right, I've adjusted my answer and the fiddle, it should work now.

Comment: Now it works perfectly! Thanks a lot for the help, really appreciated!

Comment: Hi, sorry if I come to you after months, but I'm working on your script and trying to learn more about it. Do you think it's possible to set the progress of the bar moving along with the mouse hover? Something like the [player here](http://www.hillydilly.com/) on the top. This was my recent version of the player: [http://jsfiddle.net/7s2joet2/51/](http://jsfiddle.net/7s2joet2/51/)